# How to use more than one custom structure for permalink on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

We know that, we can set a permalink structure for wordpress from settings. But, this setting is global. that means, a single structure can be saved only. Now, I want that, for some certain different kind of posts(based on category), url structure will be different.

For Example, my current permalink structure is set to "post name", like "http://localhost/wordpress/sample-post/"

Now for a specific category(say "mytest") it should follow the structure "http://localhost/wordpress/mytest/sample-post/"

To achieve this, I found only one plugin named "advance permalink"(http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/) . But it has some problems. Initially doesn't work at all(with latest version of wordpress). even If I fix it and get working (I did already), still occurs some other problems, like paging functionality for home page get lost. So, I am in need of some alternative solution.

Can anyone suggest some other plugin that can help achieve my goal or some hints to achieve it by some custom coding please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that by fiddling with the HTACCESS file , but I would not reccomand it .
Have you tried this plugin ??

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I think, its close enough to fit to my needs. Just tried with little tweak and its working :D . Thanks for the link...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know whether there is a specific plugin which addresses your needs, 
but generally speaking you need to use the WordPress' Rewrite API.

Comment: yes, I think so. However, I am not expert wp plugin developer. So, it will may take time for me to adapt that. That's why I was looking for some close solution that I can tweak quickly to meet my needs. Thanks.